# Using Ui-select with multiple categories in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, drop-down-menu, ui-select

I'm trying to create a search dropdown with multiple category types with ui-select. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to flatten my data in order make this work. I can make one category work, but not multiples.

Something like this:

[image]

Right now my code looks something like this, which only shows the name category:

```
 <ui-select ng-model="data.selected">
       <ui-select-match placeholder=" ">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
       <ui-select-choices repeat="item in flatData | propsFilter: {name: $select.search}">
           <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
       </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
```

Has anyone ever had to do something like this, could someone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use ui-select group by in this way, you'd have to restructure your data to look something like this:

```
[{
    category: 'Locations',
    name: 'Sydney'
},
{
    category: 'Locations',
    name: 'Hong Kong'
},
{
    category: 'Locations',
    name: 'New York'
},
{
    category: 'Names',
    name: 'Bob A.'
},
{
    category: 'Names',
    name: 'Andrew S.'
},
{
    category: 'Names',
    name: 'George M.'
}]
```

Now you can group this data by the parameter "category", like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="data.selected">
    <ui-select-match placeholder=" ">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices group-by="flatData.category" repeat="item in flatData | propsFilter: {name: $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```